# How to select from two different columns based on one having a null value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following example data in Oracle.

Table Name

```
 ID     Name       city
  1     Atik        1
  2     Tania       null
  3     Anabia      3
```

Table City

```
  ID     Name
  1       A
  2       b
  3       C
```

I am trying to select a value from table CITY if the value in table NAME is null, otherwise I want the value in NAME. The result should look like this:

Result

```
  ID     Name       city
  1     Atik        A
  2     Tania       null
  3     Anabia      B
```

This is only 3 columns, but I have a lot of columns like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [correlated subquery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357), in this way:

```
SELECT id, name,
       (SELECT Name FROM City c
        WHERE c.id = n.city ) as City
FROM Name n
```

You can also use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT n.id,
       n.name,
       c.name as city
FROM Name n
LEFT JOIN City c
ON c.id = n.city
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=600cdfc1cbf08b8bc2798229f02a3d96

```
| ID |   NAME |   CITY |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |   Atik |      A |
|  2 |  Tania | (null) |
|  3 | Anabia |      C |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NVL2` to check for `NULL` value in table `Name`:

```
SELECT n.ID, n.Name, NVL2(n.city, c.Name, NULL) AS City
FROM Name n LEFT JOIN City c 
ON c.ID = n.city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join on the ID field, and then use a `CASE` statement to choose your value. It should be flexible enough to help with your other columns too.

```
SELECT
    n.ID,
    n.NAME,
    CASE WHEN n.CITY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE c.NAME END AS CITY
FROM
    NAME n LEFT JOIN CITY c ON n.ID = c.ID
```